# Recursive Query: "Table Doesn't Exist" inside function, but does outside function

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm trying to wrap a recursive temporary table query inside a function on MariaDB 10.3.7 on Ubuntu 18.04. I've tried breaking the statement down to the more basic parts but it all works correctly until I put it all together.

This is an example of the statement I want to turn into a function:

```
with recursive Descendants as (
    select * from Characters where id = 91402
    union
    select c.* from Characters as c, Descendants as d
        where d.id = c.mother_id or d.id = c.real_father_id
) select count(distinct(id)) from Descendants
```

It print out the number of descendant characters, which is what I want.

And here is my attempt so far at turning it into a function:

```
create function count_descendants(cid int unsigned) returns int unsigned return (
    with recursive Descendants as (
        select * from Characters where id = cid
        union
        select c.* from Characters as c, Descendants as d
            where d.id = c.mother_id or d.id = c.real_father_id
    ) select count(distinct(id)) from Descendants
);
```

Maria accepts this, but if I try to use it:

```
select count_descendants(91402);
```

It prints this error message:

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 12: Table 'ck2.Characters' doesn't exist
```

"ck2" being the name of the database being used. I can post the schema if something would like to see that.

Edit: I have submitted it as a bug on MariaDB's bug tracker: [MDEV-16629](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-16629)

Comment: Try specifying the table with the database and schema names.  "ck2.dbo.Characters"

Comment: I don't know what that is but including the "dbo" in the name produces a syntax error. Using "ck2.Characters" has the same result as not including the database name.

Comment: Then try replacing the table name "Characters" with "ck2.Characters"

Comment: That's what I tried, it didn't make a difference. I wouldn't expect that to be the problem since I have `use ck2;` at the beginning of the script I'm running these in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a [bug with recursive CTE queries in MariaDB, has been confirmed, and was fixed.](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-16629)